# How to return data from onDataChanged Method

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read a node in my database and return the value retrieved in a single method. When i run the code the data is logged on the console but the method returns a null value.

**What i Know**:

I know that Firebase retrieves/synchronizes with the database automatically in the background therefore the code inside onDataChanged is executed last.

**What i don't know**:

How to get my method to return the value gotten from the onDataChanged method.

My code:

```
public static String telephone;
public static String getMyNumber(){
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("phone");
    r.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            telephone = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("YourTag", telephone);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return telephone;
}
```

Comment: Your `getMyNumber` method runs synchronously on the main thread. The data is retrieved from the Firebase Database asynchronously on a separate thread. If you're targeting regular Java/JVM, you can use semaphores to synchronize the two. On Android this is not possible. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705

Comment: ok thanks for the comment. i am working on Android.

Comment: In that case you have no other option then embracing the asynchronous nature of Firebase (and most modern cloud services).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to asynchronous programming. When you attach the listener by calling `addValueEventListener`, your app don't automatically get the value (or the `onDataChange` doesn't get called directly.

If you are about to update the UI after the `telephone` is retrieved, then put the code inside the `onDataChange` method.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you should use Callbacks:

Ex.:

```
private InterfaceListener mListenerForResult;

public Contructor(InterfaceListener listener) {
    this.mListenerForResult = listener;
}


public static String telephone;
public static String getMyNumber(){

final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("phone");
    r.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            telephone = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("YourTag", telephone);
            mListenerForResult.obtainValue(telephone);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return telephone;
}

interface InterfaceListener {
    obtainValue(String telephone);
}
```

From the other class:

You should implement this inferface, and pass through the constructors.